# How to save and retrieve an array of dictionary arrays

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift, plist

I have an array of dictionary arrays that the app revolves around, that needs to persist.
I can't it appears save this to NSUserDefaults.
I probably could use CoreData if I had experience with it, but it seems overkill, and I only need to collect the data once on launch and save once on close.

So I am trying to figure out how to write this to a plist file (if possible) on save.
And retrieve it on application launch.

The data :

```
// Declare var
var recordingsDictionaryArray = [[:]]
// Populate many times during app use
recordingsDictionaryArray.insert(["name":saveRecordingField.stringValue, "date":NSDate(), "path":recorder.url], atIndex: 0)
```

So the dictionaries contain a mixture of String, NSDate, and NSUrl

Can this be saved to a plist file in my applicationSupport folder..?
Hopefully without breaking it apart on save and reconstructing it on launch.

I am trying an example, but i can't get it to work at all if i do not reference [0] to the data var. If i just say var data = recordingsDictionaryArray I get errors :

```
func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // add some dummy content to the empty recordingsDictionaryArray
    recordingsDictionaryArray.insert(["name":"Recording One", "date":NSDate(), "path":"dummy path"], atIndex: 0) // dummy content
    recordingsDictionaryArray.insert(["name":"Recording Two", "date":NSDate(), "path":"another dummy path"], atIndex: 0) // dummy content
    recordingsDictionaryArray.insert(["name":"Recording Three", "date":NSDate(), "path":"final dummy path"], atIndex: 0) // dummy content

    // check the count
    var thecount = recordingsDictionaryArray.count
    println(thecount)



    var data = recordingsDictionaryArray[0] // if i do not add reference to item [0] data errors below
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    var path = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.plist")
    var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if (!(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)))
    {
        var bundle: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("recordings", ofType: "plist")!
        fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle, toPath: path, error:nil)
    }
    data.objectForKey(data)
    data.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    // I only get "Recording 3" saved to the plist
}
```

Re Answer 1 below: 
I Feel like i was close to getting there with NSUserDefaults, but don't know how to get mutableRetrievedDictionary back into recordingsDictionaryArray as it was before save.

```
    // save
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(recordingsDictionaryArray, forKey: "recordingsArray")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()



    // retrieve
    var mutableRetrievedDictionary: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("recordingsArray")?.mutableCopy()
```

Comment: Just be aware that when data coming back from NSUserDefaults is always immutable and will need to be changed into mutable again.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can save this to NSUserDefaults.
Try this:

```
let standard = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() //Helps when you call it a lot
var recordingsDictionaryArray : NSMutableArray!

//SAVE
standard.setObject("anyObject", forKey: "myKey")
standard.synchronize()

//RETRIEVE
recordingsDictionaryArray = standard.objectForKey("myKey") as NSMutableArray
//Force the object called back to be mutable again
```

Comment: Thank's for the heads up, i thought i was on a losing battle with NSUserDefaults. A feel i am close to doing it this way, but can't quite clinch it. See update at the bottom of my question. Thank's.

Comment: If you are answering the question, then consider adding the actual code comprising the solution. Otherwise your answer will likely be deleted

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of semi educated trail and error, I found a solution that will work for me in this case, using NSUserDefaults :

```
func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // add some dummy content to the empty recordingsDictionaryArray
    recordingsDictionaryArray.insert(["name":"Recording One", "date":NSDate(), "path":"dummy path"], atIndex: 0) // dummy content
    recordingsDictionaryArray.insert(["name":"Recording Two", "date":NSDate(), "path":"another dummy path"], atIndex: 0) // dummy content
    recordingsDictionaryArray.insert(["name":"Recording Three", "date":NSDate(), "path":"final dummy path"], atIndex: 0) // dummy content


    // Save to NSUserDefaults
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(recordingsDictionaryArray, forKey: "recordingsArray")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Get the data back

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    recordingsDictionaryArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("recordingsArray")?.mutableCopy() as Array
```